# I'd like to add a sub-header image to a specific tagged page in my Tumblr theme

Tags: tags, themes, tumblr

Very simply, like the title says.

I have a single specific tag that I'd like to have it's own header image when viewed.

http://teratoma.tk/tagged/dreams

I just don't know if anything exists within Tumblr's codex to do it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add this code to your HTML (preferably before {block:Posts}):

```
{block:TagPage}
   <h2 class="tag" id="{Tag}">Posts tagged "{Tag}"</h2>
{/block:TagPage}
```

This code adds another header to every tagged page. If you prefer not to have headers on other pages not marked as "dreams," you need this code:

```
h2.tag { display: none; }
```

To hide the header text and make your custom sub-header image appear when it's in the "dreams" tag page, you need to add this to your CSS:

```
h2.tag#dreams{ 
  display: block;
  color: transparent;
  background-image: url('header URL');
  height: ##px;
  width: ##px;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure what I might be doing wrong. I'm getting the text "Posts tagged (the tag)" on EVERY tagged page, with no image.

Comment: I can't paste the whole thing here, so here's a link: http://dl.rickey-rat.com/reduxredux-tagged.txt